# Set object to intial value by looping through keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object that I want to allow to be reset. The type of `mockData[key]` and `cloneDeep(initialState[key])` seems to be `Todo | User`, so I'm not sure where the intersection in the error is coming from.

```js
const initialState = cloneDeep({
  todos: mockTodos,
  user: mockUser,
});

export const mockData = {
  ...initialState,
  reset: () => {
    keysOf(initialState).forEach((key) => {
      mockData[key] = cloneDeep(initialState[key]); // Type 'User | Todo[]' is not assignable to type 'Todo[] & User'.
    });
  },
};
```

Full error message:

```
Type 'User | Todo[]' is not assignable to type 'Todo[] & User'.
  Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'Todo[] & User'.
    Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'Todo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2322)
```

Util `keysOf` function:

```js
/*
 *  This provides a way of having the response be of the form:
 *    "keyOne" | "keyTwo"
 *  instead of simply being of type string[]
 */
export function keysOf<T extends Object>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> {
  return Array.from(Object.keys(obj)) as Array<keyof T>;
}
```

Copy/pastable reproducible example:

```js
/*
 *  This provides a way of having the response be of the form:
 *    "keyOne" | "keyTwo"
 *  instead of simply being of type string[]
 */
export function keysOf<T extends Object>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> {
  return Array.from(Object.keys(obj)) as Array<keyof T>;
}

interface Todo {
    id: number
    text: string
}

interface User {
    id: number
    name: string
}

const mockTodos: Todo[] = []
const mockUser: User = {
    id: 0,
    name: "John"
}

const initialState = {
  todos: mockTodos,
  user: mockUser,
};

export const mockData = {
  ...initialState,
  reset: () => {
    keysOf(initialState).forEach((key) => {
      mockData[key] = initialState[key];
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without undeclared values like `cloneDeep`, `mockTodos`, or `mockUser`.  Ideally I could just paste your code into my own IDE and get to work solving your problem instead of first trying to reproduce it

Comment: I've updated the post with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation or missing feature of TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693).  [TypeScript is *incomplete*](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1544414378383925250) in this regard, since it can't verify that the line `foo[k] = bar[k]` is safe when `foo` and `bar` are of compatible types and `k` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of compatible keys.  It's fundamentally the same issue as in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) but with assignments instead of functions.  The compiler checks *types* and not *values*, and it does these checks *once* for each line of code instead of once for each possible narrowing.  So because it's unsafe to allow `foo[k1] = bar[k2]` where `k1` and `k2` are different variables of the same union type as `k`, then the compiler sees `foo[k] = bar[k]` as unsafe.  For now this is a limitation.

---

Until and unless this changed, the workaround approach is to rewrite that assignment so that the key type of `k` is of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `K`, and that `foo` and `bar` are of identical types (say `FooBar`).  The compiler will allow you to write `FooBar[K]` to `FooBar[K]` if `K` is generic.  It's still potentially unsafe, but the compiler allows it.

Here's what it looks like for your example:

```
type State = typeof initialState;
export const mockData = {
    ...initialState,
    reset: () => {
        keysOf(initialState).forEach(<K extends keyof State>(key: K) => {
            const md: State = mockData; // safely upcast
            md[key] = initialState[key]; // State[K] = State[K] is allowed
        });
    },
};
```

So the `forEach()` callback is now generic; `key`'s type changes from `keyof State` to generic `K` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof State`; and I widen `mockData` to `State` (via a new variable).  The line `md[key] = initialState[k]` is allowed because both sides are seen as being of type `State[K]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling I was running into a Typescript limitation, I just wasn't sure what I could search to find more information about it. Thanks for clearing it up.